# Changing Fancybox2 iframe css inline

Tags: css, iframe, inline, fancybox-2

I have several situations where I need to change the css for a Fancybox iframe inline, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that.

---

**EDIT - Partial Success**
Changing the options inside the function changed the iframe's height, width and padding, however wrapCSS didn't work with that and I therefore couldn't adjust the font color or size. I also couldn't combine it with the other methods listed below.

```
parent.$.fancybox({
content: "Thank you for creating an account",
         type : 'iframe',
 padding : 50,
         width: 50,
         height:50,   
});
```

---

Other methods I've tried:

1. Assigning a class
2. Setting the css in the javascript - $(this).css({...})
3. Setting the iframes css in the script - $("#customer_info").css({...});
4. Adding a class to fancybox-wrap - $('.fancybox-wrap').addClass('thank_you');

Method #3 (setting the iframe's css in the script) successfully changes the css for the iframe's content, but doesn't change the css of the iframe's container.

An example of where I need to do this is when a customer submits a form and the success message displayed requires a different layout (most importantly the iframe's height and width).

```
success: function () {                           
   $("#customer_info").fadeOut("fast", function(){
   $(this).before("Thank you for creating an account");
   setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 1000);
   });                         
}
```

I'm using Fancybox2, and other layout issues require me to set this inline as opposed to allowing the iframe to resize to fit the content (unless there is a way to override that in just one place without resizing the iframe for any other content what's displayed)

I came across this script on another post which I believe should work if I could figure out the correct way to insert it into my code.

```
$('.fancybox-inner').height($(this).contents().find('body').height()+30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update two css classes.  The .fancybox-inner to resize the content and the .fancybox-skin to resize the skin.

```
$('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').replaceWith('<body>Thank you</body>')
$('.fancybox-inner').css('width', 200);
$('.fancybox-skin').css('width', 200);
```

You could can also use

```
$.fancybox.update()
```

but that only updates the FancyBox height to the height of the content.

Your best and cleanest option is just to open up a new fancybox with the thank you message.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting either method to work :-( Would you mind showing me where to insert it?

Comment: Have you tried to open up a new fancybox?  As said that would be preferred.  
The code works from the main document.  If you execute it from within the fancybox then you'll need to add top.$(... before it to get the proper jQuery context.

Comment: I've taken your suggestion to heart and would like to open a new iframe (as long as there's no visible delay) :-) I've had some trouble figuring out how to do that since this script is on the iframe page and not the parent which called the iframe. Would you know how to do that? Every method I've tried terminates the script before opening a new iframe because the iframe running the script has been closed.

Comment: I finally found one way to do it, but I'm not sure if it's the best way:  parent.$.fancybox.open({ href : 'iframe2.html', type: 'iframe', padding : 0, scrolling: 'no', helpers: {overlay: {closeClick: false, css : {'background' : 'rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.85)'}},}, });
parent.$.fancybox.close({ href : 'iframe1.html'});